# Android - set Dot on random position in imported image

Tags: java, android, android-studio

thanks in advance!!!

Situation:
Me and a friend has to develop an app for the university. (I think this story is common?!) We had the idea for an App, where you take or import a picture and the App make one random dot/point on this picture.
So if you stand in front of a shelf in the store and dont know which of the beers/Liqours/crisps/... you should buy, take a picture and the random dot picks for you.

Problem:
We had an imageview, where to import the picture. Go to gallery or take a photo is working. But I dont know how to set a dot in this imageView/picture. At the moment i put a second imageview over it, where a random text including "•" appears. Its more like a workaround.

Code for the dot in Class MyCanvas:

```
int min = 5;
int max = 500;

Random r = new Random();
int i1 = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
int i2 = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint pBackground = new Paint();
        pBackground.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 512, 512, pBackground);
        Paint pText = new Paint();
        pText.setColor(Color.RED);
        pText.setTextSize(40);
        canvas.drawText("•", i1 , i2, pText);
    }
```

---

onClick method:

```
public void click_button_magic(View view) {
    View v = new MyCanvas(getApplicationContext());
    Bitmap bitmap =Bitmap.createBitmap(500/*width*/, 500/*height*/, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    v.draw(canvas);
    ImageView iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_point);
    iv2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

If i change this code to the imageview where the imported pictures get in, the picture get white after clicking on the "Magic" button.

What i want to change:

- set dot (not text)
- set dot in imported image
- getting from image the max and min dimension within to set the dot (width, height)

I think for this tasks i made something fundamental wrong. But i dont know what... =(

So I hope you can help me (code or tips to get on the right way)

Thank you very much and i hope my english is good enough to understand my problem!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard for me to understand how you did this, because I can't see all of your code. But if I would have done this project, I would use a FrameLayout, and add the Photo with:

```
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

And then make a small view with round background, and make the margin left margin right be random. That way you don't need to draw on the canvas and all that hassle.

Comment: thank you for your help and your idea, your idea was brilliant, but to much work for me =(. Meanwhile i get a solution i will post here

Answer (score 0):

meanwhile i get a solution for getting a point in the picture.

To set an image as imageview:

```
...
imageview.setImageBitmap(image);
        bm = image;
        iv = imageview;
...
```

bm is now the bitmap with the wanted image
iv is the imageview

Now the Clickfunction:

```
public void click_button_magic(View view) {

    //bei jedem Klick wird das Bild neu geladen, damit bei erneutem Klicken ein neuer Punkt erscheint
    iv.setImageBitmap(bm);

    ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.imageView_photoImport);
    img.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = img.getDrawingCache();

    //get Maße des IMG
    int targetWidth = scaledBitmap.getWidth();
    int targetHeight = scaledBitmap.getHeight();

    Bitmap targetBitmap =  loadBitmapFromView(iv, iv.getWidth(), iv.getHeight());//Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth,targetHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    //get random coordinates
    int min = 5;
    int maxWidth = targetWidth;
    int maxHeight = targetHeight;

    Random r = new Random();
    int randomWidth = r.nextInt(maxWidth - min + 1) + min;
    int randomHeight = r.nextInt(maxHeight - min + 1) + min;

    //Paint object
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
    canvas.drawCircle(randomWidth, randomHeight,20, paint);
    img.setImageBitmap(targetBitmap);
}

public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v, int width, int height) {
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width , height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    v.layout(0, 0, width, height);
//Get the view’s background
    Drawable bgDrawable =v.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable!=null)
//has background drawable, then draw it on the canvas
        bgDrawable.draw(c);
    else
//does not have background drawable, then draw white background on the canvas
        c.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    v.draw(c);
    return b;
}
```

I hope it will help someone in the future...maybe not, maybe it will